# what are EIO=3&transport=websocket in websocket url

Tags: websocket, socket.io

wss://www.mysite.ca/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket

This is how chrome webdevoloper tools shows the request url of a socket io.

I am trying to understand more about EIO=3&transport=websocket .

I have to invoke the url from an API tool

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These are query parameters that the socket.io client sends to the socket.io server as part of the initial connection request.

`EIO=3`, I believe, is the version number of the engine.io sub-system in socket.io.  If the server is not compatible with this version number, it will likely fail the attempt to connect.

`transport=websocket` says that socket.io wants to use the websocket protocol as the eventual transport.  socket.io has several different transports it supports including web polling and a flash-based protocol.

To connect to socket.io server, you will need a full-fledged socket.io client.  You can't make a socket.io connection by just sending a URL from a tool to the server.  There's a lot more involved than that in establishing a working socket.io connection.

Comment: Man, this really threw me off, I was pulling my hair with the websocket working in a couple sites but not a third one <_<, turned out, yes, I needed EIO=3

Comment: @DanielAngel - The `EIO=3` is only used with  socket.io connections, not plain webSocket connections.  And with  a socket.io connection, you must be using a socket.io client library that will automatically include the EIO=xx anyway.  This answer is to explain what the socket.io client library does and what you might see in the browser network tab, not for manually  building a webSocket connection.

Comment: Correct, but both client and server need to use the same version, I updated my client and it was using EIO=4, but the server was rejecting it. I downgraded my client to V3 as I'm not able to easily upgrade the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've seen a couple questions on socket.io that you've answered well so it seems you're great at it.. please what exactly do you mean by ```You can't make a socket.io connection by just sending a URL from a tool to the server```.. could you explain a bit more on this statement and also could I get your discord name or something to have a few minutes conversation with you..thanks in advance

Comment: @Bombosonic - What I mean is that starting a socket.io connection needs a full-blown socket.io client and server.  While a socket.io connection all starts with an http connection, that connection is quickly upgraded to a different protocol and both sides need to know how to speak that protocol.  The underlying transport is webSocket and then there's a socket.io data layer on top of the webSocket.  Both sides have to know how to speak all that.  Thus a generic http server or even a generic webSocket server will never make a socket.io connection.

Comment: @jfriend00 Let's say I want to make use of a socket.io client library and I have no special access to the server I want to connect other than being a normal user.. would the ```"full-fledged" socket.io client``` mean just emitting and receiving events?

Comment: @Bombosonic - Does the server support socket.io client connections?  And, support doing something by sending it messages?  If so, then you can connect to it from any socket.io client.  A socket.io client knows how to speak the socket.io layer on top of the webSocket protocol, knows how to connect to a socket.io server and knows how to send/receive socket.io messages.  It's really not clear what scenario you're asking about.  If the server you want to connect to doesn't have specific socket.io support built-in, then you can't connect to it with a socket.io client.

Comment: @jfriend00 The website uses socket.io as it's means of transport and doesn't use polling but goes straight to websocket as it shows this in devtools ```{
    "sid": "9fIYu28PI5hXU5O6GsOj",
    "upgrades": [],
    "pingInterval": 25000,
    "pingTimeout": 5000
}``` ...looking at devtools i could see the messages sent from the server to the browser client and from browser client to the server...

Comment: @jfriend00 are you on discord

Comment: @Bombosonic - If you have a specific question, it seems like you should write your own question and include all the details of the question.  Comments on someone else's question are not the right place to discuss your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't have a 'specific' question but rather multiple cause of my inability to fully understand the socket.io concept even after watching multiple videos and reading documentation that's why I'm tryna get a few minutes of speaking time with you

Comment: @Bombosonic - I'm not sure how to help further if you don't have a "specific question".  I can't really offer a tutorial on how socket.io works here in comments on some other question.

Comment: @jfriend00 please check this out. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75719557/what-would-be-the-reason-and-solution-for-the-websocket-error-mesage-when-runn