# What would be the reason and solution for the "websocket error" mesage when running nodejs socket.io client code

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I ran this socket.io v2.5.0 code using nodejs and I came across this issue..
So how could i solve this problem and what is the reason behind this issue in the first place..originally when I ran the code in the browser it kinda worked.. I'm making use of two libraries  socket.io version2.5.0 and socket.io wildcard... I've looked everywhere for the cause of this error but still have not seen anything about this

This right here is the error that I received in my terminal

```
Error: websocket error
    at Transport.onError (/home/BoMbO/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js:68:13)
    at ws.onerror (/home/BoMbO/node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/websocket.js:163:10)
    at WebSocket.onError (/home/BoMbO/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:140:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at abortHandshake (/home/BoMbO/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:731:15)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/BoMbO/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:604:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:701:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22) {
  type: 'TransportError',
  description: ErrorEvent {
    target: WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _binaryType: 'arraybuffer',
      _closeCode: 1006,
      _closeFrameReceived: false,
      _closeFrameSent: false,
      _closeMessage: '',
      _closeTimer: null,
      _extensions: {},
      _protocol: '',
      _readyState: 2,
      _receiver: null,
      _sender: null,
      _socket: null,
      _bufferedAmount: 0,
      _isServer: false,
      _redirects: 0,
      _url: 'wss://ws2.basqu.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket',
      _req: [ClientRequest],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    type: 'error',
    message: 'Unexpected server response: 403',
    error: Error: Unexpected server response: 403
        at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/BoMbO/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:604:7)
        at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (node:_http_client:701:27)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22)
        at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
        at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
        at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
        at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
  }
}
```

And this right here is the nodejs clientside code

```js
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('wss://ws2.basqu.com/', {
    path: '/socket.io',
    reconnection: true,
// options of the Engine.IO client
    transports: ['websocket'],
    transportOptions: {
        websocket: {
            extraHeaders: {
                origin: 'https://basqu.com'
            }
        }
    },
    upgrade: false,
    rememberUpgrade: true,
// options for Node.js
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    extraHeaders: {
         origin: 'https://basqu.com'
    }
});

socket.on('connect', () =>{
    const sid = socket.id;
    console.log(`Connected with session ID: ${sid}`)

    socket.emit("authorization",{"session":"FlaqiaG...iiii..loveee.you....OX","isDemo":1});

    socket.on("instruments/list", () => {
        console.log('received: instruments/list')
    });

    socket.on("s_authorization",() => {
        console.log('received: s_authorization')
    });

    let lastTickTime = 0; // track the last time "tick" was sent

    function sendTick() {
      const now = Date.now();
      const elapsedTime = now - lastTickTime;

      if (elapsedTime >= 60000) { // send "tick" if at least 1 minute has elapsed
        socket.emit('tick');
        lastTickTime = now;
      }
    }
    setInterval(sendTick, 500);
    
    socket.on("orders/closed/list",() => {
        console.log('received orders/closed/list')
    });
    socket.on("orders/opened/list",() => {
        console.log('received order/opened/list')
    });

    socket.emit("indicator/list");

    socket.emit("drawing/load");

    socket.emit("pending/list");

    socket.emit("instruments/update",{
        "asset":"AUDCAD_otc",
        "period":60
    });

    socket.on("s_drawing/load", () => {
        console.log('received: s_drawing/load')
    });

    socket.on("settings/list",() => {
        console.log('received: settings/list')
    });

    socket.on("s_balance/list",() => {
        console.log('received: s_balance/list')
    });
    socket.on("s_indicator/list",() => {
        console.log('received: s_indicator/list')
    });

    socket.on("s_chart_notification/get",() => {
        console.log('received: s_chart_notification/get')
    });

    socket.on("pending/list",() => {
        console.log('received: pending/list')
    });
   
    socket.on("history/list/v2",() => {
        console.log('received: history/list/v2')
    });

    socket.on("quotes/stream",(data) => {
        console.log(`received quotes/stream event with data: ${data}`);

        const utf8Data = new TextDecoder().decode(data);

        console.log("Received UTF-8 encoded data: ", utf8Data);
    });

    socket.on("depth/change",() => {
        console.log('received: depth/change')
    });

    socket.emit("chart_notification/get");

    socket.emit("depth/follow","AUDCAD_otc");

    socket.emit("settings/store",{"chartId":"graph","settings":{"chartId":"graph","chartType":2,"currentExpirationTime":0,"isFastOption":false,"isFastAmountOption":false,"isIndicatorsMinimized":false,"isIndicatorsShowing":true,"isShortBetElement":false,"chartPeriod":4,"currentAsset":{"symbol":"AUDCAD_otc"},"dealValue":1000,"dealPercentValue":1,"isVisible":true,"timePeriod":60,"gridOpacity":8,"isAutoScrolling":1,"isOneClickTrade":true,"upColor":"#0FAF59","downColor":"#FF6251"}});

});


socket.on('*',(event,data) => {
    console.log('Received event: ${event}, with data: ${data}')
});

socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log(reason)
});

socket.on('connect_error',(err) =>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a webSocket server?  Or a socket.io server?  A socket.io client requires a socket.io server.

Comment: @jfriend00 connecting a socket.io client to a socket.io server

Comment: Something doesn't look right when I see this file in the stack trace `/home/BoMbO/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js`.  That looks like the `ws` module.

Comment: What do you think could be wrong

Comment: Well, you are getting a 403 response status which is supposed to mean you don't have proper permissions to access this resource.

Comment: How could the websocketError be solved though I still dont get it